# SQL - how to pull all transactions based off a list of ID's

Tags: sql, join

I know this will be a relatively simple query but it is stumping me...I have a list of Distinct customer ID's and a list of transactions which include customer ID as an attribute. Not all of the customers in the transaction data are on the list. I want to pull the transaction list that is just those from my list of customer ID's. how would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds like you are looking for a specific kind of `JOIN` but we need more information to help you. Please post a sample of the data you're working with and the data you'd like to get as a result of your query.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include sample data and your attempt at the SQL in your post.

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we can't reproduce your problem with the info you've provided.

Comment: Gordon was able to discern the issue and articulate a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A typical method would be `in`.  If the list is something you provide, you would do:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where customer_id in ( 1, 2, 3, . . . );
```

If the customer ids are in a table, you can use the same construct:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where customer_id in ( select c.customer_id from customers c );
```

Depending on your database, there might be more efficient ways to write the latter query.